# Python; django-rest-framework - Unusual inheritance behaviour

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've got a chain of inheritance that looks like this:

```py
class _PermissionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = self.Meta.model
        self.model_unique_keys = self.model.Meta.unique_together
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class PermissionsManagementGroup(UUIDmodel, UserModel, DateTrackedModel):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "management_group")


class PermissionsManagementGroupSerializer(_PermissionsSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PermissionsManagementGroup
        fields = BASE_FIELDS + ("management_group", "group_info")
```

The problem I'm having is that on instantiating `PermissionsManagementGroupSerializer` I am getting `Exception Value: type object 'Meta' has no attribute 'unique_together'`.

After some investigation I found that at the point of instantiation, inside the `__init__` in `_PermissionsSerializer`, `self.model.Meta` is `<class 'UUIDmodel.Meta'>` and not `<class 'PermissionsManagementGroup.Meta'>`. I am not clear why this is the case so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`self.Meta.model.Meta.unique_together`

you are definitely referencing the Meta of a wrong model.

Comment: If you paid more attention at my code, you would have noticed that I do
`self.model = self.Meta.model; self.model_unique_keys = self.model.Meta.unique_together` which is effectively the same as `self.model_unique_keys = self.Meta.model.Meta.unique_together`
Yet, to give you the benefit of the doubt, I did try it your way but nope, it doesn't work.